# Environment variables for Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I am following [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) to get model attachments stored in S3. I am curious as to why the AWS key and secret and bucket name need to be stored in config/environments/production.rb AS WELL AS set using

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
```

I thought it would be one or the other. For obvious reasons, I would rather not store the key and secret in a file in a repo.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the steps. I now see that the production and development file are not supposed to contain the API Key and Secret. Just reference the environment variable.

Comment: Exactly. Use `ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]` or `ENV.fetch("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")` the later will raise an error if the variable is nil and is very useful for catching config errors.